# Motherboard light on and ethernet blinking but computer won't turn on

Tags: desktop-computer

I was changing plugging in a monitor in the back of my pc and at some point between me crawling under the computer and when I went to turn the new monitor on the computer shut down. Now it wont turn back on. The ethernet light blinks and there is a light on the motherboard but nothing else. I'm not sure what caused this or what the next step is.

I unplugged everything except the keyboard. I also unplugged the powersupply from the ups for a few seconds and tried plugging it back in and trying it again. Nothing has worked. The computer is plugged into a ups so I don't think it was a surge. Plus the timing is suspicious since I was fiddling around with the cables at the back.

Comment: If you plugged in a new monitor but the motherboard light is on, are you implying the computer is running but no display is showing? Have you checked to see what input setting the monitor is on?

Comment: @DrZoo I guess I wasn't too clear. The motherboard light was on and so was the ethernet light but other then that the computer did not appear to be running. No fans or display at all. I only have ssds so I couldn't check for spinning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect then that it is just the display that is the problem.

try a different monitor, or different cable.

try removing and re-inserting the graphics card ? i recall one time i set up a computer and it had no display, and i pushed the graphics card a little harder in, and the next time i booted the display worked. soon after, someone else mentioned that they had built a computer and they'd had exactly the same problem.

does the hard drive make a spinning sound, assuming you aren't using an SSD ?

Comment: I reseated the graphics card and like magic all the fans started right up and everything worked. I'm still at square one on my triple monitors working but at least now I'm no longer spazzing because I might have blown out something else. Thankyou so much.

Comment: i'm glad it worked ! honestly not what i'd expected, but i guess it must be a common problem

Answer (score 1):

If your keyboard is PS2 style , make sure you havent got it in the wrong port , this can actually cause damage if plugged into the mouse port - ie it has been known to blow a tiny onboard resistor.
Check if your keyboard lights flash on boot up - usually a good indication.
But yes, basically just have power, keyboard (and mouse), Screen Plugged in
even unplug usb stuff.
All else fails - could be dust, unplug everything (especially mains), carefully remove cover, quick and careful hoover, also possibly eject and reinsert Memory Modules

Comment: I didn't know that about the ps2 port. I thought they were interchangable. However I did have it in the right port.